# Fake 404 error on IIS 7.5 logs

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5

I've been reviewing the log files (W3C) of my high traffic asp.net website hosted under IIS 7.5 and i'm getting a lot of images with 404 errors.. yet, these images do exists.

When I try to load them, they load perfectly fine (status 200). And when you check the log again for other occurencies of the same image it shows status 200.. meaning it loaded fine for other users.

Any idea why? Perhaps because of timeout?